# How i can use GetElementId() to get button in geckowebbrowser?

Tags: button, click, getelementbyid, geckofx, getelementsbyclassname

How i can use `GetElementId()` to get button in geckowebbrowser?

I used:

```
GeckoButtonElement button = new GeckoButtonElement(
    geckoWebBrowser1.Document.getElementById("your_button_id").DomObject);
button.Click();
```

Please help me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write

```
geckoWebBrowser1.Document.getElementById("your_button_id").click()
```

?